# Different terminal "sort" results of files with same set of texts

Tags: shell, sorting, unicode, terminal

The files shown below contain the same set of lines in different order. In fact, both of them have already been sorted via `sort <filename>` (You can try to sort them yourself); however, the results show the 4th and 5th lines are switched wrt each other. How can this happen? Why does the terminal `sort` command sort files in different order?

File 1

```
w_±_± w_±_± 1
w_˚ w_˚ 1
w_ฌ w_ฌ 1
w_㎡ w_㎡ 1
w_ℓ w_ℓ 1
```

File 2:

```
w_±_± w_±_± 1
w_˚ w_˚ 1
w_ฌ w_ฌ 1
w_ℓ w_ℓ 1
w_㎡ w_㎡ 1
```

Comment: This kind of question **really** needs to specify the locale you're using, particularly with respect to character type and collation order.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting!  It must be something related to the locale settings.  I can get it to work in the C locale:

```
$ LC_ALL=C sort file1
w_±_± w_±_± 1
w_˚ w_˚ 1
w_ฌ w_ฌ 1
w_ℓ w_ℓ 1
w_㎡ w_㎡ 1

$ LC_ALL=C sort file2
w_±_± w_±_± 1
w_˚ w_˚ 1
w_ฌ w_ฌ 1
w_ℓ w_ℓ 1
w_㎡ w_㎡ 1
```

At first, I though this might be due to the length of the character codes, so perhaps the character is composed of two bytes where the first byte is the same.  Let's investigate that:

```
$ printf 'w_ℓ w_ℓ 1' |hd; printf 'w_㎡ w_㎡ 1' |hd
00000000  77 5f e2 84 93 20 77 5f  e2 84 93 20 31           |w_... w_... 1|
0000000d
00000000  77 5f e3 8e a1 20 77 5f  e3 8e a1 20 31           |w_... w_... 1|
0000000d
```

`ℓ` is `e2 84` while `㎡` is `e3 8e`, so that's not what's going on here.

This is probably because your locale indicates skipping over those characters for some reason.  This is true for en_US.UTF-8 with `sort` from GNU coreutils 8.28, at least.